# Gram-Schmidt in characteristic two?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, orthogonality

I was helping someone work on a computing problem with bit vectors that reduced to finding a basis knowing a spanning set, and realized quickly that the Gram-Schmidt process does not work as expected in characteristic-2. Since orthogonality was not a requirement anyway I came up with an alternate approach, but it left me wondering: Is there a way to salvage Gram-Schmidt in this setting (a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2 = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$) to get a meaningful concept of orthogonal basis? (Orthonormal seems out of the question since I don't see a way to define a meaningful norm.)

Comment: Is the [Gröbner Basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gröbner_basis) what are you looking for?

Comment: To simply extract a basis from a set of generators, Gauß elimination into row echelon form should suffice.

Comment: "Inner products" (=the sum of products of components) are not a reliable tool for detecting linear (in)dependece in characteristic two. It may happen that an entire subspace is orthogonal to itself. For example many interesting error-correcting codes (= linear subspaces of $\Bbb{F}_2^n$) have this property.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Yes that's essentially what I did.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Could you expand on that to make an answer? Is there any other definition that can replace inner-product orthogonality to recover useful properties, or is orthogonality just largely meaningless in characteristic 2?